# Cannot connect to MySQL during Migration in workbenck. Can't connect to MySQL (10061) (code 2003)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, database-migration

I'm using MySql Workbench to connect to a remote MySQL instance. I have a connection setting that allows me query tables, create tables... but it fails when I try to migrate data from Microsoft SQL Server to MySQL.

Here are the steps:
Database -> migration... Enter the connection data for Source DBMS -> test connection pass. Enter the source DBMS select the existing saved connection -> test connection pass. Go to next step.

I receive the error `Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (10061) (code 2003)`.

Below the complete log. Any ideas?

```
> Starting...
Connect to source DBMS...
- Connecting to source...
Connect to source DBMS done
Check target DBMS connection...
- Connecting to target...
Connecting to Mysql@localhost::3306@localhost:32222...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 5.2 CE\modules\db_mysql_fe_grt.py", line 137, in connect
    con.connect()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 5.2 CE\workbench\db_utils.py", line 169, in connect
    raise MySQLError(modules.DbMySQLQuery.lastError(), modules.DbMySQLQuery.lastErrorCode(), "%s@%s" % (self.connect_info.parameterValues["userName"], self.connect_info.parameterValues["hostName"]))
workbench.db_utils.MySQLError: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (10061) (code 2003)
Connecting to Mysql@localhost::3306@localhost:32222...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 5.2 CE\modules\db_mysql_fe_grt.py", line 137, in connect
    con.connect()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 5.2 CE\workbench\db_utils.py", line 169, in connect
    raise MySQLError(modules.DbMySQLQuery.lastError(), modules.DbMySQLQuery.lastErrorCode(), "%s@%s" % (self.connect_info.parameterValues["userName"], self.connect_info.parameterValues["hostName"]))
workbench.db_utils.MySQLError: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (10061) (code 2003)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 5.2 CE\workbench\wizard_progress_page_widget.py", line 65, in run
    self.func()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 5.2 CE\modules\migration_source_selection.py", line 450, in task_test_target
    raise e
SystemError: MySQLError("Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (10061) (code 2003)"): error calling Python module function DbMySQLFE.connect
ERROR: Error during Check target DBMS connection: MySQLError("Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (10061) (code 2003)"): error calling Python module function DbMySQLFE.connect

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 5.2 CE\workbench\wizard_progress_page_widget.py", line 543, in update_status
    task.run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 5.2 CE\workbench\wizard_progress_page_widget.py", line 80, in run
    raise e
SystemError: MySQLError("Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (10061) (code 2003)"): error calling Python module function DbMySQLFE.connect
ERROR: Exception in task 'Check target DBMS connection': SystemError('MySQLError("Can\'t connect to MySQL server on \'127.0.0.1\' (10061) (code 2003)"): error calling Python module function DbMySQLFE.connect',)
```

Comment: This is a bug. Please report it in http://bugs.mysql.com

Comment: Specifically I had similar issue and this "bug" was it. Transfer over SSH isn't supported: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69650

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error in MySQL Workbench 5.2.47 with two MySQL databases which work fine otherwise. It seems like a bug and I am surprised Oracle released a non-working wizard.

A workaround is to use Server Administration in Workbench for the two databases and use Data Export and Data Import/Restore respectively. However, this only works if you migrate from MySQL to MySQL. In addition, Data Export/Import functionality is buggy too.